# How to graphically compare several columns with a single column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to print a bar chart that compares several columns to a reference using pandas.

```
    id_point    dens_app       BD_0-30    BD_30-60    BD_60-100   BD_100-200
5      002      1.423063      1.393333       1.38        1.37       1.38
188    026      1.193980      0.000000       0.00        0.00       0.00
189    026      1.017998      0.000000       0.00        0.00       0.00
225    027      1.256524      1.403333       1.38        1.36       1.36
226    027      1.393999      1.403333       1.38        1.36       1.36

df.mean().plot.bar(rot=0, width=0.6)
```

[image: enter code here]

I would like to place the 'dens_app' column next to each 'bd_' column as seen in the image.

Comment: They look like they are next to the `dens_ap` bar.

Comment: I would like to put the 'dens_app' column next to each column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataFrame.mean() returns a series.

```
s = df.mean()
>>> s
id_point      21.600000
dens_app       1.257113
BD_0-30        0.840000
BD_30-60       0.828000
BD_60-100      0.818000
BD_100-200     0.820000
dtype: float64
```

You can select items in any order you want.

```
>>> s[['dens_app','BD_0-30','dens_app']]
dens_app    1.257113
BD_0-30     0.840000
dens_app    1.257113
```

Use that to plot your bar chart.

```
s[['dens_app','BD_0-30','dens_app','BD_30-60','dens_app','BD_60-100','dens_app','BD_100-200']].plot.bar()
```

---

Using the Series `s = df.mean()` make a DataFrame of the *BD* values.

```
>>> r = pd.DataFrame(s[2:],columns=['BD'])   
>>> r
               BD
BD_0-30     0.840
BD_30-60    0.828
BD_60-100   0.818
BD_100-200  0.820
```

Add a *dens_app* column.

```
>>> r['dens'] = s['dens_app']
>>> r
               BD      dens
BD_0-30     0.840  1.257113
BD_30-60    0.828  1.257113
BD_60-100   0.818  1.257113
BD_100-200  0.820  1.257113
```

Plot that DataFrame.

```
r.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

---

[image: your plot]